# Multiple Select with wp_dropdown_categories wordpress

Tags: wordpress, categories

I want to add a widget that shows a category list with the latest post shown. However i have found the plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-posts/  But this plugin shows only one category at a time. When i open the widget file cat-posts.php I saw the code wp_dropdown_list . So can you tell me how can make this to select multiple categories to show all categories with latest post. Is it possible or there is another way to do the same task. Please suggest.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can check:

```
wp_category_checklist()
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_category_checklist

You can define a custom walker and change the check-boxes to drop-down with multiple select.