# WordPress dropdown multiselect option

Tags: php, wordpress, select, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

I have the below code for WordPress dropdown single select option.
I want to make this code work with multiple selection option, but dont know how.
Please give a solution.

```
<?php 
        $args=array(
                'class'       => 'select-submit2',
                'hide_empty'  => false,
                'selected'    => $prop_action_category_selected,
                'name'        => 'prop_action_category',
                'id'          => 'prop_action_category_submit',
                'orderby'     => 'NAME',
                'order'       => 'ASC',
                'show_option_none'   => __('None','wordpress'),
                'taxonomy'    => 'property_action_category',
                'hierarchical'=> true
            );

           wp_dropdown_categories( $args );  ?>
```

Kind regards

Nikoleta

Comment: From [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246781/multiple-select-with-wp-dropdown-categories-wordpress), you can use [wp_category_checklist](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_category_checklist). Have you tried that?

Comment: yes I have read this article, but couldent handle, could you explain

Answer (score 2):

The `wp_dropdown_categories()` function is a WordPress function that creates a dropdown of categories.  You can specify how and what you want it to output based on passing various arguments to the function.

However, there is no argument that the function accepts to change it from a single to a multiple select list.

A simple approach is to alter the output that the function gives you after it is generated. This isn't always the best approach to everything, but in this case, there are two key elements that make this a simple approach:

1. While the function echoes (prints) its output by default, it accepts an argument to simply return the HTML result without outputting it (allowing you to change it before it is displayed).
2. Changing a dropdown to a multiple select list is as simple as adding "multiple" to the HTML tag (i.e. changing `<select>` to `<select multiple>`)

You can call the function, placing the results in a variable before it is output, then use PHP's `str_replace()` on that result to slip "mulitple" into the select tag:

```
/**
 * Your args from the question
 * plus turning echo off.
 * Note the change to the name (adding "[]")
 */
$args = array(
    'class'       => 'select-submit2',
    'hide_empty'  => false,
    'selected'    => $prop_action_category_selected,
    'name'        => 'prop_action_category[]',
    'id'          => 'prop_action_category_submit',
    'orderby'     => 'NAME',
    'order'       => 'ASC',
    'show_option_none'   => __('None','wpestate'),
    'taxonomy'    => 'property_action_category',
    'hierarchical'=> true,
    'echo'        => 0,
);

/** get the dropdown **/
$dropdown = wp_dropdown_categories( $args );

/** insert "multiple" using str_replace **/
$multi = str_replace( '<select', '<select multiple ', $dropdown );

/** output result **/
echo $multi;
```

Passing the "echo" argument of "0" tells the function not to output anything (add any other arguments to the array as needed).  Then `str_replace()` is run on the result, and the result of that is what you output.

Note that you'll need to change the "name" argument to pass an array to be able to pass/get all of the selected items.

Comment: <?php
               $dropdown = wp_dropdown_categories($args);
$dropdown = str_replace( '<select', '<select multiple ', $dropdown );
print $dropdown;?>

Comment: The function echoes its result by default so you need to make sure that your $args include setting echo=0.  For example - $dropdown = wp_dropdown_categories( array( 'echo'=>0 ) );  Otherwise, the result will be output before the str_replace is run.

Comment: I use the code below and it is showing no results "empty multiselect fields"                       <?php 
            $args=array(
                    'class'       => 'select-submit2',
     'echo'       => '0',
                    
                );

               wp_dropdown_categories( $args );  
      ?>
               <?php 
               $dropdown = wp_dropdown_categories( array( 'echo'=>0 ) );
$multi = str_replace( '<select', '<select multiple ', $dropdown );
echo $multi;?>

Comment: You're kind of off track. I edited the example in the answer to hopefully be more clear - added comments and the $args you had in the original question.

Comment: Thank you, I have try the example selecting two or more values in the dropdown and press the submit button, but unfortunately the system only saves one value.

Comment: Good point. When using a multiple select, you need to pass (and receive) the values as an array.  I edited your example arguments to change the name from 'prop_action_category' to 'prop_action_category[]' (note the addition of "[]").  This will pass the selections as an array so that you get all selections.

Comment: Good morning butlerblog,                                                                      Now with **prop_action_category[]**  settings nothing is submitted the value stays the same

Comment: It is passed as an array. You can't handle it as a string. (Also, you still receive it as $_POST['prop_action_category'] not $_POST['prop_action_category[]'])

Comment: ok thank you, I understand, but in my case it is not working like the code above.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories#Notes) you would need to use `wp_category_checklist()` instead. However if you are in need of a dirtier solution this one should help:

```
$dropdown = wp_dropdown_categories($args);
$dropdown = str_replace('id=', 'multiple="multiple" id=', $dropdown);
```

Comment: Thanks appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

In a simple and powerfull way, just add this code to your `functions.php` file

```
add_filter( 'wp_dropdown_cats', 'wp_dropdown_cats_multiple', 10, 2 );

function wp_dropdown_cats_multiple( $output, $r ) {

    if( isset( $r['multiple'] ) && $r['multiple'] ) {

         $output = preg_replace( '/^<select/i', '<select multiple', $output );

        $output = str_replace( "name='{$r['name']}'", "name='{$r['name']}[]'", $output );

        foreach ( array_map( 'trim', explode( ",", $r['selected'] ) ) as $value )
            $output = str_replace( "value=\"{$value}\"", "value=\"{$value}\" selected", $output );

    }

    return $output;
}
```

And add multiple arg like below:

```
<div class="ci-select">
    <?php
        wp_dropdown_categories( array(
            'taxonomy'          => 'property_location',
            'hierarchical'      => true,
            'show_option_none'  => esc_html_x( '-', 'any property location', 'ci_theme' ),
            'option_none_value' => '',
            'name'              => 's_property_location',
            'id'                => 'property_location',
            'selected'          => isset( $_GET['s_property_location'] ) ? $_GET['s_property_location'] : '', // e.x 86,110,786
            'multiple'          => true
        ) );
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good approach, but it needs more clarification/explanation for people who don't know what you're doing and why.